# Best way to deploy a projector screen from the bottom?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, statics

I want to design a system for an electronically deployable projector screen, where when not in use the screen is stored at the bottom and there are no structural elements sticking up significantly, but once the screen is deployed it is pulled up from the bottom. I am currently stuck on how to ensure the system is stable once deployed, as I have investigated both scissor lift mechanisms and telescoping poles, but I don't see how to ensure stability in the extended state.

Comment: How much stability do you need? When a screen is deployed from above, they are usually just weighted sails and will shift in the wind from someone walking by. Also how big/tall of a screen are we talking here? are we looking at something in the 72" range or are we talking something like IMAX? Now they also have inflatable screen for beach and park shows too that would deploy from the bottom upward

Answer (score -1):

A pull cord.

Or fixed threaded rods and rotating nuts that then drive the rods up taking the screen with them. That way the rods will only be "visible" when extended, but covers can also be arranged.

Comment: Hey Downvoter, where is your better answer?